# Que pasa si no libero recursos (set objeto = Nothing)?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Me ha surgido una duda muy básica, después de muchos años programando con ms Access.

Cuando navego por internet, frecuentemente me encuentro con liberación de recursos, al utilizar recordset's, databases, u otros objetos:

`set objeto = nothing`

Trabajo en un proyecto muy grande, el cual nunca ha liberado los recursos. Llevo muchos años manteniendo ese proyecto, y nunca he sabido valorar el efecto que tiene el no usar esa liberación al final de los métodos.

En algunas partes he leído que existe un recolector de basura automático, lo que no daría sentido a esa "liberación de recursos" dentro de código. Aunque no estoy seguro si ese recolector hacía referencia a vba, vb6, o vb.net

Si que detecto que, con el tiempo, el proyecto va incrementando su tamaño. Aunque siempre he atribuido ese crecimiento como algo normal del propio Access.

Por ejemplo, se generaban muchas consultas temporales con una símbolo ~ al inicio, y entiendo que quizás esas consultas hagan uso de memoria en el proyecto, y haga crecer su tamaño. Pero, si no me equivoco, creo que esas consultas se generan al usar consultas sobre recordsource's, combos, listas, o similares.

cuando programo y hago pruebas, también crece de manera brutal el tamaño de las aplicaciones.

En cualquier caso, el proyecto siempre ha mitigado esos crecimientos utilizando compactaciones/reparaciones de vez en cuando sobre las bases de datos. TAmbién utilizo esas compactaciones después de programar y realizar las pruebas

Alguien sabe la importancia de aplicar o no aplicar esa liberación de recursos?

Comment: En principio las variables liberan su memoria en cuanto salen del alcance... Así que el tiempo que llevo en este foro en inglés, la gente que sabe mucho dicen que no es necesario porque se libera automáticamente.... Yo tampoco suelo percibir diferencias entre liberar a mano o cuando acaba el procedimiento y se libera automáticamente. De hecho me pasa cuando trabajo con clases que si termina la macro y tenía muchos datos, tarda un rato mientras libera la memoria ocupada.

Comment: Es cierto que hay un recogedor de basura, pero no es bueno delegar en él, es mejor limpiar el objeto una vez dejes de usarlo. Pongamos un caso concreto: una función donde manejas `N` objetos, abres el objeto `1`, los usas y no le aplicas `Nothing`, abres objeto `2` lo usas y no aplicas `Nothing`, abres objeto `999` ... mientras estés en el ámbito de esa función vas a tener `N` objetos abiertos sin necesidad. Imaginemos un uso concurrente  de `X` usuarios por `N` objetos... podrías tener ahí un problema. Por eso es mejor que el programador controle de forma explícita sus objetos.

Comment: Sugiero que leas las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/517006/5587982) y sus comentarios.

Comment: A mí el comentario de @A.Cedano me parece una respuesta válida, y más con el link proporcionado.

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo apenas casi 3 años en ms-access en un proyecto grande, cuando genero un formulario, es sano realizar validaciones de datos, para asi permitir o no que el usuario avance, entonces, con esas validaciones en subformularios, a veces, suelo utilizar recordsets, y me pasaba seguido que, la propiedad BOF era un error muy recurrente, se debe a lo que mencionas, pero... hay excepciones, por ejemplo, os recordsets si estas en un proceso es utilizado e inmediatamente sales... como una consulta por ejemplo, pues no pasa nada, ya que el proceso termino, y queda en el famoso "Recolector de basura", que aun no se muy bien como funciona, pero ahi esta; pero, si no finaliza el proceso, recordemos que los Recordsets funcionan mediante conexiones... entonces si la conexion no se hay finalizado, ahi es donde se generan los errores por liberación de recursos; en objetos mas avanzados como no se, la libreria de WinSock, por mencionar algo... pues, no sucede esto y da igual si lo cierras, o liberas recurso, por buenas practicas, he aprendido que es mejor realizar una validacion de recursos para no errar, solo son 3 lineas mas, pero como te menciono, no siempre es necesario, ya todo depende con lo que estes trabajando.

Para realizar la liberacion de recurso, usandolo como buena practica, sin importar que se genere un error, basta con una sencilla validacion, que pudemos inbestigar en internet si el objeto en cuestion, cuenta con alguna propiedad que permita realizarla, en el caso de los recordasets, es muy sencilla:

```
    On Error GoTo Error

    ''CUERPO DEL CODIGO        

    Salir:
''      Esta es la validacion.
        If Recordset.Status = 1 Then
            Recordset.Close()
        End IF
    
    Error:
        Resume Salir
        Exit Sub/Function
```

Y Asi nos evitamos sorpresas, OJO: Depende del objeto con el que estes trabajando.